# Get value from MySQL query made with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm running aquery with ajax, this is a part of it:

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user'"); 

$count = mysql_fetch_array( $count );

$count[0]
```

I want to get the value from `$count[0]` and asign it to a javascript variable so I can use it on my code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you try `json_encode()` ??

this is how i used to be:

```
<?php
...
// my logic
...

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($count[0]);
?>
```

and in the javascript :

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var data = eval ("(" + xmlhttp.responseText + ")");
  }
}
```